# Interpreting result of a toboggan problem (special cases)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

[image]

Assuming there **is** friction contrary to the question above,

I derived the equation as in my textbook:

$$a_x=g(\sin\alpha-\mu_{k}\cos\alpha)$$

Testing special cases, if $\alpha=90°$,$a_x=g$, just as we would expect in a free fall. However, letting $\alpha=0°$, we get
$$a_x=-\mu_{k}g$$
Shouldn't $a_x=0$ as on a horizontal surface?

Comment: Not if friction is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The friction force $F_nμ_k$ only applies **while the body is moving**, and this force's direction is opposite to the movement direction.

In your formula $a_x=g(sin\alpha-\mu_{k}cos\alpha)$, you effectively subtract the friction force from the gravitational acceleration force, **assuming that there is movement in positive x direction**.

So, $a_x=-\mu_{k}g$ is perfectly valid in case you started with some positive speed. Then the friction will continuously slow down the toboggan to a halt.

After that, the friction force reduces itself to the amount necessary to compensate the gravitational acceleration force.

Answer (score 1):

At critical angle :
$$ \alpha_{_{th}} = 2 \arctan \left( {\sqrt{\frac {1}{\mu_{k}^2} + 1} - \frac 1\mu_{k}} \right) $$

and below, toboggan will stop moving due to kinetic friction force will overcome gravity speedup. This will make $a_x = 0$, so afterwards involving kinetic friction term will be meaningless, because body will be at rest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but in the in x-direction the value for $\hat {g}$ disappears because g is also a vector with no x-component making $a_x =0$.

Comment: This is wrong, the equation $a_x = g(\sin\alpha - \mu_k\cos\alpha)$ being the projection on the $x$-axis, nothing is a vector anymore, including $g$

Comment: You think g suddenly stops being a vector?

Comment: Not "suddenly", but after projection on the $x$-axis. Be careful not to mix the vector $\mathbf{g} = (g\sin\alpha, g\cos\alpha)$ and its norm $g$.